# What's the difference between scoring and arranging?

Tags: terminology

Sometimes, I read "this song was arranged by someone", and "this song was scored by somebody else".

What's the difference between scoring some music and arranging it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the definition a score is:

> a written form of a musical composition; parts for different instruments appear on separate staves on large pages; "he studied the score of the sonata"

[Definition of score](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/musical+score)

Whereas arrangement is:

> In music, an arrangement is a musical reconceptualization of a previously composed work. It may differ from the original work by means of reharmonization, melodic paraphrasing, orchestration, or development of the formal structure.

[Definition of arrangement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrangement)

So a score is a way of laying out a piece of music but an arrangement is a *different* way of playing an existing piece of music.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say the conceptual difference is

- Scoring is putting the notes down on paper for a band/orchestra to read.
- Arranging is actually being responsible for deciding what those notes may be.

The arranger may not physically write the score, that job may be given to a transcriber.

**But** I'd also say both are otherwise used so interchangeably that my definition cannot be relied on to separate the 2 acts in everyday usage.

Answer (score 5):

'Scoring' is a somewhat vague word that could mean a number of activities that involve writing a score. It it often used to mean writing a whole set of *accompanying* music:

```
James Roy Horner has scored over 100 films.
```

It is also often used in the form "scored for", telling us what instruments the piece is written for. In this sense it could mean the same as *arranged*:

```
This piece is scored for strings and woodwind.
```

Arranging is the act of writing music such that it is suitable to be played by a certain instrument or ensemble. So we can say

```
 Eleanor Rigby features a double string quartet arrangement by George Martin.
```

In which context we are talking about *Eleanor Rigby* as an original composition. However, if we say

```
Tonight's concert will feature an arrangement of the Mission Impossible theme 
for theremin, sousaphone and recorder
```

then it's clear that we are talking about a new version of an existing piece of music.